# Add double quotes (") to apple script for do shell script

Tags: macos, applescript

I have an AppleScript

```
do shell script "echo hello \" Mr. X\" "
```

I should get the output 
    hello "Mr. X"
But, I get output 
    hello Mr. X

I am using OS 10.10.5 Yosemite

How can I add double quotes to Mr. X using above script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable syntax is using `quoted form of`:

```
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of "hello \"Mr. X\""
```

or use single quotes to escape the whole argument:

```
do shell script "echo 'hello \"Mr. X\"'"
```